# missing attribute when using find_by_sql with RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, find-by-sql

I use a find_by_sql statement which works fine in development.
When it comes to the test environment using spec, it outputs the error:

ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: registered

I have run db:test:purge and db:test:prepare to clean up the test database.
But the error still occurs.
In development and test I use PostgreSQL.

The problematic statement is the following:

```
def registered_friends
  User.find_by_sql(
  ["select users.id, users.first_name from users inner join friendships
    on users.id=friendships.friend_id
    where friendships.user_id = ?
    and users.registered = true",self.id])
end
```

Comment: Did you check your test database? Is the registered field present?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sebastien,

I found the problem.
In my model I initialize the field "registered" to set it by default to "false".
As the SQL-query didn't return the field "registered", it broke at this point.
I found it after it also broke in development stage.